# Using Google Cloud Storage with rsync

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am new to Google Cloud. We have historically used AWS for online backups -- essentially, our local servers ran rsync to an EC2 instance at AWS and it all worked fine. I'm now trying to migrate from AWS to Google and of course the setup is pretty different. With gsutil rsync it looked to me as though I wouldn't need to spin up a Compute Engine at all, I could just push stuff straight into gs://aws_mnt bucket

Having installed the SDK on our AWS instance I was able to push all our backups to the gs://aws_mnt bucket very easily using gsutil cp -n

But going forward I want to run a cron job on the local server which uses rsync rather than cp for obvious reasons.

I have two issues:

1. Despite reading the appropriate documentation ([here](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#serviceaccounts)) I am so stupid I can't figure out how to permanently authorise the local server so I don't have to do gcloud auth login and get a code from a browser each session, as for a cron job that's not really going to work.
2. When I try to use gsutil rsync from the local server to the gs://aws_mnt bucket that was pre-populated from AWS, I get an error:

gsutil rsync /mnt/archive/backups gs://aws_mnt/kahless
Building synchronization state...
Skipping cloud sub-directory placeholder object gs://aws_mnt/kahless/
Starting synchronization

There is some discussion of this error [on github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/209) and I've produced detailed output from

gsutil -D -m rsync /mnt/archive/backups gs://aws_mnt/kahless

But since this is a brand-new install of the SDK I can't imagine the thread hasn't already been dealt with so I must be doing something wrong?

Rus

Answer (score 1):

In response to your questions:

1. Once you have configured credentials using gcloud auth, the 'gcloud auth login' command will cause them to be selected until you login to a different credential... and that state will persist and not require you to go through the browser session again unless/until you revoke those credentials. Note: If you're thinking of running commands from an unattended script (e.g., via cron) please consider using service account credentials. For more details please see https://developers.google.com/cloud/sdk/gcloud/#gcloud.auth
2. That "skipping..." message is not an error - it's just informing you that gsutil is skipping trying to download the placeholder object, because such objects aren't needed in (and would interfere with) directories in the local file system. I'll update the message in the next version of gsutil to make this more clear. So, what you saw was that the second run of gsutil rsync found nothing to do after comparing the source and destination, and completed normally.

Comment: I am trying to rsync a bucket into an empty bucket and I get the message about skipping the placeholder. The destination bucket is empty, so I have no idea whats going on. I am using the following "gsutil -m rsync -n -p -d -r gs://bucket1 gs://bucket2" - this fails, but I can rsync targeted directories in bucket1....

Comment: Mr Pablo@ - when you say that rsync command fails do you mean it's not copying objects? You specified the -n option, which causes rsync to run in "dry run" mode. If you leave that option off it should copy the objects for you.

Comment: Sorry, I was running the command without the -n option. And when it failed, yes, it failed to copy the objects. I got the "skipping" message, despite the destination bucket being totally empty.

Comment: Mr Pablo@ - please send the exact command you're trying to run to gs-team@google.com, to my attention, so I can investigate further.